# On $\mathbb R^2$ consider the distance $d: \mathbb R^2 × \mathbb R^2 → \mathbb R_{+}^{0}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, continuity, metric-spaces

I could really do with a solution or any help with the following question.

On $\mathbb R^2$consider the distance $d: \mathbb R^2 × \mathbb R^2 → \mathbb R_{+}^{0}$

given by

$d((x, y),(u, v))$ = 
$|x − u|$ if $y = v$

$d((x, y),(u, v))$ = $|x| + |u| + |y − v|$ if $y$ does not equal $v$

(a)  Sketch the balls $B_2$$((0, 0))$, $B_2$$((1, 0))$, $B_2$$((2, 0))$ of radius $2$ around the points 
$(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0)$.

(b) Let $f : \mathbb R → \mathbb R^2$

$f(t) = (g(t), h(t))$ for $t ∈ \mathbb R$ be a function with components

$g, h: \mathbb R → \mathbb R$. Assume that $f$ is continuous with respect to the standard distance on $\mathbb R$ and the distance $d$ on $\mathbb R^2$
and that $f(0) = (2, 5)$.

Prove that
there is $c > 0$ so that $h(t) = 5$ for all $t ∈ (−c, c)$

If anyone has a solution to either part I'd appreciate you sharing it here

I'm just unsure on how to sketch this around the given points. It is probably simple, I am just not familiar with this topic.

If i want a ball $B_2(0,0)={(x,y)∈\mathbb R^2:d((x,y),(0,0))<2 =(x,y)∈\mathbb R^2:|x|+|y|<2}$

Is $B_2((0,0))$ a ball of radius $2$ within a square of length $2$ with the centre located at $(0,0)$ with corner points $((2,0),(-2,0),(0,2),(0,-2))$

Comment: What have you tried? It's not hard, but math.stackexchange is not here to do your homework. It's here to help you on your tries :)

Comment: @Luke I have edited the question to include my attempt as the first sketch

Comment: You are correct about $B_2((0,0))$. However, you will find balls of radius $2$ about other points are not squares. In fact, they are very oddly shaped. Once you've figured out what shape they are, the 2nd part should be more clear. Plotting the ball of radius 2 about $(u, v)$ is the same as plotting the inequalities $$|x - u| \le 2, \quad y = v$$ and $$|x| + |u| + |y - v| \le 2, \quad y \ne v$$.

Comment: Thank you. So for example second ball sketched would just be ball of radius 2 contained within the plotted inequalities you provided with $u=1$ and $v=0$.